# Controlling hotplate by power source

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, control, heat

I am interested in setting up a control circuit for a system that is heated by hotplates. They are standard lab grade hotplates with dials that modulate heat output (arbitrarily scaled 1-10).

In order to set up a control circuit I would like to be able to simplify the control of these hotplates so that I can modulate their power source instead of physically turning the dials. This is mainly because I plan on incorporating a PID controller which operates on a single manipulated variable (like current), and I would prefer not to use a servo on the dials for fear of loss of accuracy.

So:

1) What is the underlying mechanism of current regulation via a hotplate dial?

2) What would be the safest way to attenuate power to a hotpad (with a microcontroller)?

If you are worried about safety (and foresee me burning down my lab), I will not be undertaking this project alone and will be seeking help from an real live electrical engineer. However I would like to have a solid plan and minimize the amount of time they have to spend helping me. My understanding of circuitry is limited to introductory E&M and basic arduino circuits.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find that they use what is called an "infinite heat control", which is an electromechanical time-proportioning controller that works similarly to a light dimmer. It works by switching the power on and off with a varying duty cycle that is achieved mechanically (with a bimetal strip and mechanical contacts).

On the other hand, there may be some kind of crude electronic controller in there like a light dimmer. Perhaps with a triac and diac phase control.

In either case, chances are it will be unsuitable for use directly because of a lack of galvanic isolation. You may be able to repurpose the triac (if there is one) by adding an optotriac isolator to it,  but an SSR would likely be easier and safer.

In any case, you do not likely want to control current, you want to control power directly if possible. The best way to do that is to chop the power to the element so that the power is linear and proportional to the duty cycle.

P.S. If the knob moves easily like a light dimmer, it's probably an electronic control. If it's a bit harder to turn, like a home range top adjustment, then it's probably an infinite heat control.

In any case, grab a screwdriver, pop the cover and have a look. All should be clear.

Comment: Ok well I certainly don't have the skill/knowledge to alter the hotpad's control element, so would it suffice to leave the knob on 10 (or some constant setting) and then use PWM to vary the input? Is this essentially an AC dimmer that you are recommending?

Comment: I suggest opening it up and seeing what's in there first, including any safety devices such as overtemperature cutoffs. Unplug it first, of course.

Comment: You can also work upstream and use a variac. Most lab heater controllers will pwm a variac set ac pulse to the heating element. If you can bypass the internal regulation, omega is a popular vendor of such control devices, benefit would also come in precise temperature control with a thermocouple